# trying to print on webpage with some time interval , but it is waiting for all the time and printing at once

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to get the output first as apple and then banana with some time interval of 2 secs and again a banana ... but the actual output I am getting on the webpage after the page is waiting for the 10secs (5 * 2secs). I am new to servlets.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("apple");
        pw.println("<br>");

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            pw.println("banana");
            pw.println("<br>");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot know whether a browser will update the page with partial content or wait to read everything.

Comment: You need to disable buffering.

Comment: What if you flush the output (`pw.flush();`) after each time you write?

Comment: Flushing the output each time i write did not help .

Answer (score 2):

Servlet code runs on the server EXCLUSIVELY, the output you see is the result of running the servlet.   The code does not run in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do some async support to your servlet but you are doing it wrong, (thread.sleep is going to sleep the current thread, and write anything after flush operation will cause IllegalStateException) you should use new servlet3.0 api if you want to send to the client async response, I mean wait for some time to send another part of the response. You should read Servlet3.0 (not sure if it can be done using previous API but I'm sure this works with Servlet3.0 async support)

http://docs.coreservlets.com/servlet-3.0-api/\

Async suport need to be enable in web.xml or using @WebServlet annotation.

This tuto is a good starting point.
http://www.journaldev.com/2008/async-servlet-feature-of-servlet-3